# Writing file from array with = in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file, post, isset

I have this code:

```
require_once("./templates/install.html");

if(isset($_POST["proceed"]))
{
$phpfile = fopen("db_config.php","w");
$configdata = array(
'dbhost'        => $_POST["dbhost"],
    'dbname'        => $_POST['dbname'],
    'dbuser'        => $_POST['dbuser'],
    'dbpasswd'      => $_POST['dbpass'],
    'table_prefix'  => $_POST['prefix'],
);
```

How can I save this array into the created php file so it'll be as following:

```
<?php
$dbhost=$_POST["dbhost"];
$dbname=$_POST["dbname"];
....
?>
```

And etcetera...

Like, first the variable name in the array as a variable in the new php file equals the value.

Comment: This sounds like a Very Bad Idea.

Why do you want this?

Comment: To give the clients an option to chose their database in the system, I'm making some sort of system with content management.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php



$string = '<?php 

$dbhost = "'. $_POST["dbhost"]. '";

$dbuname = "'. $_POST["dbuname"]. '";

$dbpass = "'. $_POST["dbpass"]. '";

$dbname = "'. $_POST["dbname"]. '";

$prefix = "'. $_POST["prefix"]. '";

$user_prefix = "'. $_POST["user_prefix"]. '";

$dbtype = "'. $_POST["dbtype"]. '";

?>';



$fp = fopen("config.php", "w");

fwrite($fp, $string);

fclose($fp);



?>
```

Comment: The code doesn't work, it saves nothing to the file, tried echoing, didn't work either.

Comment: Please check the $_POST have values before saving.

Comment: I did, they are fine. I think it has something to do with the <?php tag, I tried even:

     $configdata = '<?php';

 var_dump($configdata);
 echo $configdata;

and it showed nothing.

Comment: User echo htmlspecialchars($configdata); to print. Unless '<?php' will show blank.